# A general formula for a set of numbers that satisfy two conditions.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose that $n$ is a positive integer that satisfies the following system $(X)$:

$$n=60k_1+1 ;$$ $$n=7k_2 ;$$ for some integers $k_1, k_2$.

(Or you can write it in modular arithmetic form)

The question is: What is the general formula that generates all the positive integers that satisfy the two equations above?

My attempt: I have found the following formula that generates an infinite number of solutions:

$n=60(5+7t)+1$, where $t=0, 1, 2, 3, ...$

But how to prove that my formula produces all the possible solutions for the system $(X)$ above? Or, if not, then can anyone find a counter-example that solves $(X)$, but that can't be written in the form that I have found?

Comment: Have you learned the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: @saulspatz no, i haven't. Can't be shown using an elementary method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your solution can also be written, by distributing the multiplication, as those numbers of the form $301 + 420t$ - that is, those $n$ that are congruent to $301$ mod $420$. Thus, it suffices to show that for every pair of solutions $n$ and $n'$ to your equations, their difference is a multiple of $420$.

To do this, suppose that you have two solutions:
$$n=60k_1+1$$
$$n=7k_2$$
$$n'=60k_1'+1$$
$$n'=7k_2'$$
Then, their difference has the property that:
$$n-n'=60(k_1-k_1')$$
$$n-n'=7(k_2-k_2').$$
In particular, their difference is a multiple of both $60$ and $7$. This is equivalent to saying that their difference is a multiple of the least common multiple of $60$ and $7$, which is $420$.

More generally, this argument suffices to show that any solution to a set of equations of the form $n\equiv a_i\pmod{m_i}$ is unique mod the LCM of the moduli - and if you're a bit careful, you can also use this as a lemma to show that if the moduli are pairwise coprime, a solution must also exist - which is the Chinese Remainder Theorem. (Though this is not how you would usually show existence because it sketches a non-constructive proof for something that can be solved constructively)

Comment: I will accept this answer because it answers my question using an elementary argument.

Answer (score 2):

$7|n=60k_1+1=7(8k_1)+4k_1+1\iff$

$7|4k_1+1\iff$

$ k_1\in \{7k+5: k\in \Bbb Z\}\iff $

$n=60k_1+1\in \{60(7k+5)+1: k\in \Bbb Z\}=\{420k+301: k\in \Bbb Z\}.$

Comment: $7|4k_1+1\iff$ $ 7|2(4k_1+1)=7k_1+k_1+2 \iff $ $7|k_1+2\iff$ $ k_1+2\in \{7(k+1):k\in \Bbb Z\}\iff$ $ k_1\in \{7(k+1)-2: k\in \Bbb Z\}=\{7k+5: k\in \Bbb Z\}.$

Answer (score 1):

The [Chinese Remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) says that if the moduli are coprime there will be a solution and the solutions will recur at the product of the individual moduli.  Here that is $420$, which is the recurrence in your solution.

Comment: Because there are $420$ choices for the remainders and each one has to have a solution, there must be only one solution $\bmod 420$